# SSO Settings for Salesforce org

Tags: oauth2, single-sign-on, saml

I am trying to configure SSO to my salesforce org.

As per my understanding I have to be provided with the issuer URL, Identity Provider Certificate by the IdP.

What I want to understand is that:

1. Identity Provider Login URL
2. Identity Provider Logout URL

Does these values have to be provided by the Idp or is it generated at Salesforce end.?

Also, I understand that the entity id is the custom domain url for my salesforce org.

My second question is that:
Does the org need to have a custom domain for the SSO to work?Or can I just provide the login URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Values of IdP Login URL and IdP Logout urls should be provided by the Idp. IdP should share metadata file which can be uploaded automatically to SFDC setup when you use New from metadata option on **SAML Single Sign-On** Settings setup page.

2) No need for custom domain. You need to setup SSO in Single Sign-On menu and after that enable SSO as Authentication Service in **My Domain** setting setup page

Check out this youtube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kIA1MZrNaAE&t=2007s
It is quit long, but gives a very good understanding of SSO concepts.